# select an button or movicclip on a certain frame actionscript3

Tags: flash, actionscript, frame, timeline

I got a flash file to edit and need to add an extra function to a button in an external as file. this button will not show until on a certain timeline(that says on frame 120). the problem is I can select any elements on the stage on the timeline1(or frame1) in the external acitonscript file. but when I tried to select the button which **will** show on frame120, it tells me 'null'. I know the season is because it has not been created yet on frame1. but How I can select an element on a certain frame or how can i solve this issue using actionscript. not embedded actionscript. need to be done in external file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your code in a function and pass it to an `addFrameScript` method.

So, in your .as file, if it's scope is the movieClip who holds the button on frame 120, use `this`, otherwise I'll assume said movie clip is referenced in your external file as `mc`:

```
//first parameter is the frame number to run this script on (since frame one is actually 0, you need to subtract one from the actual frame number)
mc.addFrameScript(120 - 1, function(){  
    var btn = mc["buttonInstanceName"];
    //do whatever with your button;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. One more question, does this function come with third party plugin?